# how to extract this using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract this

Example:

```
 www.google.com
 maps.google.com
 maps.maps.google.com
```

I need to extraact `google.com` from this.

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Do you want to extract `google.com`, or the first two levels of the domain name ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the top level domain out of the hostname, you could try this:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( ".*\\.([^.]+\\.[^.]+)" ) ;
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( "maps.google.com" ) ;
if( mat.find() ) {
    System.out.println( mat.group( 1 ) ) ;
}
```

if it's the other way round, and you want everything excluding the last 2 parts of the domain (in your example; `www, maps, and maps.maps`), then just change the first line to:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "(.*)\\.[^.]+\\.[^.]+" ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on `.` and pick the last two bits.

```
    String s = "maps.google.com";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\.");
    //should check the size of arr here
    System.out.println(arr[arr.length-2] + '.' + arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

*Extracting* a known substring from a string doesn't make much sense ;) Why would you do a

```
String result = address.replaceAll("^.*google.com$", "$1");
```

when this is equal:

```
String result = "google.com";
```

If you need a *test*, try:

```
String isGoogle = address.endsWith(".google.com");
```

If you need the other part from a google address, this may help:

```
String googleSubDomain = address.replaceAll(".google.com", "");
```

---

(hint - the first line of code is a solution for your problem!)

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str="www.google.com";

 try{
       System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".", str.lastIndexOf(".") - 1) + 1));
  }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
       //handle it
  }
```

- [Demo](http://ideone.com/fgLpJ)